# Enlarge (re-size) /boot using Xubuntu 13.10, preparing to install 14.04

Tags: boot, 13.10

the installer remarks insufficient space in /boot. I've to enlarge it.
Unfortunately I don't know how. Please give me a hind. Thanks.

Comment: Boot from Live USB/DVD and choose "Try Ubuntu without Installing." (You can't change `/boot` if you boot from it.) Run `Gparted` and resize as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to resize your boot partition to make room for the new install. To do this, you need boot from the live cd, select GParted. From the drop down box on the upper right, select your boot partition. Right click on it to unmount it and the resize it from there. Make sure to save your changes and from there you can continue the install.